# Style Datatable rows at top of table

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a `Datatable` which at the top has the following:

- Items per page `dropdown`
- `Buttons`
- `Paginator`

But each item is displayed on separate `rows` but i want to add styling but not sure how.

**Current rendered HTML**

[image]
[image]

**HTML mocked using DEV-Tools**

This is how i'd like the top of the table to look but not sure how to add the additional `Bootstrap`. The lines below are the same as the above ones but inside a `form-group row` & `col`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you provide source? I mean before datatables applied to your table

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov Managed to resolve it within the `DOM`. Posted the solution i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code sorted what i was after

```
dom:
    "<'form-group row'<'col-12 text-right'B>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-6'l><'col-6'p>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-12'p>>",
```